# ASP.Net core - where does the IdentityModelEventSource log file go when running without Publishing?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging

I enable the log by setting "IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true" in my app hosted in IIS. It works fine if I publish the app - the log file will be created/updated in the "...\Publish\logs" folder. But what I really need is to generate log file when running without publishing the code so I can debug. The problem is when running without publishing, the app runs fine but I don't see the log file anymore. Where should I look for it? Is there anywhere I can configure the location of the log file?

Comment: What log plugin you use, nlog or serilog?

Comment: I am not using any 3rd party logger yet, just whatever is built-in and default.

Comment: I am working based on IdentityServer4's quickstart code I downloaded.